# Read Row from Google Sheets API to Object

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, google-sheets-api

I am pulling info from a Google Sheets document using Google.API.Sheets.V4. I am able to read the spreadsheet without a problem but I'm struggling to find a *convenient* way to convert each row into a C# object. Each row contains about 94 columns. I was thinking I could use Json.Net to convert the results to an object but the returned values don't contain any field headers so I don't know how to easily map the values. The spreadsheet has a header row. Is there some way I can include that as part of the results? Is there a more convenient way to map the values without using Json.net?

This is what the returned values look like when serialized.

```
{
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "range": "'Form Responses - 2019'!A2:CO439",
    "values": [
        [
            "6/7/2018 16:04:24",
            "Test 2019",
            "Tester",
            "19",
            "11/11/2011",
            "11 One ",
            "Onewhere",
            "ON",
            "11111",
            "11111111111",
            "someone@someplace.org",
            "wereewdd",
            "",
            "kkdllkd",
            "",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "",     
            "",
            "",
...
```

I need to map each individual row to a graph of nested c# objects.   For example I have a `Person` object that has an `Address` object property. The spreadsheet would contain the person's name, then beside it the street address, city, state etc.  I would need to map column 3 to `Person.Address.Address1`.

Comment: Do the rows have a fixed schema?

Comment: Yes, the data (columns) are always in the same order.

Comment: Thanks @dbc, would this second option allow me to map nested objects like a person object and then their associated address object?

Comment: The trouble is mapping nested objects. For example I have a Person object that has an Address object. The spreadsheet would contain the person's name, then beside it the street address, city, state etc. Using `[JsonProperty(Order = X)]` I don't see how to map column 3 to `Person.Address.Address1`.

Answer (score 0):

So I had this similar problem when trying to get my sheet values into a sql database/datagrid.

I first setup my own way of grabbing the data a little bit.

```
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets }; // Full Read, Write, View Permissions
static string ApplicationName = "Tracker";
// Function that will get the credentials used for authenticating a request
public static UserCredential SetCredentials()
{
    using (var stream =
        new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
        // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
        string credPath = "token.json";
        return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    }
}
// Function that will pull data from @spreadsheet @range
public static IList<IList<Object>> Get(UserCredential credential, string spreadsheetId, string range)
{
    var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = ApplicationName, });

    SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

    ValueRange response = request.Execute();
    return response.Values;
}
```

Then I called it like this.

```
IList<IList<Object>> client_sheet = Get(SetCredentials(), "SomeSpreadsheetId", "Client!A2:AY");
```

This function converted it into a table for my sql to handle or datagrid to bind to.

```
public static DataTable De2DList_Table(IList<IList<Object>> s)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    List<string> columns = new List<string>()
    {
        "Column Name", "Column Name", "Column Name", "Column Name",
        "Column Name", "Column Name", "Column Name", "Column Name",
        "Column Name", "Column Name", "Column Name", "Column Name", "Column Name", "Column Name",
        "Column Name", "Column Name", "Column Name"
    };

    foreach(var header in columns)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(header, typeof(string));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
        table.Rows.Add(new Object[] {
            s[i][0], s[i][1], s[i][2], s[i][3],
            s[i][4], s[i][5], s[i][6], s[i][7],
            s[i][8], s[i][9], s[i][10], s[i][11],
            s[i][12], s[i][13], s[i][14], s[i][15],
            s[i][16]
        });
    }

    return table;
}
```

Clears the local db, destructs the 2d list into a datatable and adds it to the database. Set's my datagrid to my sql table.

```
DBFunctions db = new DBFunctions();
db.executeDB("DELETE FROM Client"); // Delete everything from local database
db.loadDB(De2DList_Table(client_sheet)); // Load the database with client sheet data

JumpTable.ItemsSource = db.getDBTable("SELECT * FROM Client").DefaultView;
db.closeDBConnection();
JumpTable.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
JumpTable.CanUserAddRows = false;
```